# In Google Cloud Storage, is it possible to change the Bucket Reference from starting with gs:// to data://, http://, or https://?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to use links to my files in Google Cloud Storage in external APIs. However, all the links to the files in Google Cloud Storage start with gs:// instead of https://, and the APIs are unable to access the zip files in my Google Cloud Storage. How do I change the Bucket Reference for the bucket storing my zip files to start with data://, http://, or https:// so the APIs can access the zip files through a link? If you can't change the Bucket Reference, how do you access the links to a zip file stored in Google Cloud Storage over the internet?

Comment: Your bucket has public access?

Answer (score 2):

The scheme `gs://` is a Google Cloud tool and SDK convention.

Google Cloud Storage also provides standard HTTP endpoints.

Public objects use the following format:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME
```

For more information:

[Google Cloud Storage Request endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#access_to_public_objects)